# What is the rationale behind keeping transactions in the mempool longer after they were in an orphaned block?

Tags: dynamic-blocksize-limit, txpool

In a [question about maximum block size and mempool behavior](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-many-transactions-can-fit-in-a-block) user36303 said:

"Transactions will stay for a day in the pool before being dropped. This increases to seven days for those transactions were once in a block which was reorganized."

What is the rationale behind keeping transactions in the mempool longer if they were part of a reorg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on current transaction volume (and a small reorg) there does not appear to be a need for a 7 day period for such transaction (because they can be confirmed much faster.

However if transaction volumes suddenly much higher (before the dynamic block size limit can fully adjust) and if the reorg was substantial (very large pools of transactions being moved to the mempool) then more than one day might be needed for confirmation.

Comment: Currently, there's a RingCT transaction in the mempool for 40 hours already: [Reddit thread](https://m.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5nf7z6/why_is_this_transaction_stuck_for_37_hours/). Will it expire after 7 days if it doesn't get mined? Are those moneroj at risk for getting lost forever?